# API Call in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I need your input for creating a search results application using ReactJS. I have around 8,000 data in a database server. Should I make one api call to retrieve the data at once and save this 8,000 data in an array then filter it by search criteria or should I make multiple api calls based on what user's search criteria? Thanks.

Comment: Just fetch the data that you need from the backend.

Comment: There are lots of tools to help you with problems like this. One of such is Algolia, which has a react library. If you intend to build this your self, then you should paginate the 8,000 records, and only by default fetch for the first page. And users can navigate from page to page, which will be an offset of the previous page and the limit you set for each page.

Comment: You should fetch only the first page (top 25, for example) of the data that matches your search criteria and create pagination interface.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will fetch what I need instead of all 8,000 at once.